# stdio.h not found after fresh xcode 4.3 installed

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

After upgrading to Lion, and installing XCode 4.3 I can't get "Hello, World" to compile.

```
include <stdio.h>

int
main ( int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}


$ gcc hello.c 
hello.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

I see a stdio.h in ./SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h, but it's a little surprising
that there isn't a 10.7 version.  Did my install fail?  It reported success.

The standard solution to this problem, after some Googling, is to reinstall XCode.  But XCode is delivered through the App store with doesn't give me a re-install option. I also never saw the various other options such as "Unix development" which are referenced in other places.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a MacOSX10.7.sdk directory at all?

Comment: If you get Xcode from the AppStore, you actually download an installer which should still be in your Applications folder. So you should be able to reinstall it easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the solution is to download the "command line tools" package.  Once downloades, run the package installer and all is well.  The /Developer directory is obsolete, no longer used in Xcode 4.3

The [Apple developer web site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) is my friend

Answer (score 6):

From Xcode 4.3, open Preferences and select the *Downloads* icon. In the *Components* pane, you can install "**Command Line Tools**".

Once that is installed, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
```

That sorted it for me.

**[UPDATE]** - I just had to do this again on my laptop, and I didn't need to install the Command Line Tools. After upgrading to Xcode 4.3, running `xcode-select` was enough for command line builds to work again.

Comment: This left xcodebuild not found for me, this different path worked: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Xcode from the app store and either don't have a MacOSX10.7 SDK or you want to reinstall the SDK, you can install/reinstall only that package fairly easily.

First check if you still have the `Install Xcode` application in your applications folder. If it's there, good, if it's not, just go to the app store and download Xcode again.

Once you have that application, use `Show package contents` on it and browse to `Contents/Resources/Packages`. There there should be a pkg file called `MacOSX10.7.pkg` which when double clicked will install/reinstall the MaxOSX10.7 SDK.